# Measuring code coverage of a Python function defined as a String, given certain arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I wrote a function which takes function definition as String and parameters (a,b) as a tuple and then executes defined function with parameters.

Below is a simple test case with two functions which are executed with same arguments but have opposite conditions.

```
import coverage
import importlib


def measure_coverage_from_string(code_string, params):
    a, b = params
    temp_filepath = "temp.py"
    with open(temp_filepath, "w") as f:
        f.write(code_string)

    cover = coverage.coverage(temp_filepath)
    cover.start()

    mod = importlib.import_module("temp")
    mod.fun(a, b)

    cover.stop()
    result = cover.xml_report()
    return result

fun_def = """def fun(a, b):
    print(a)
    if a < b:
        print(b)"""

fun_def_new = """def fun(a, b):
    print(a)
    if a > b:
        print(b)"""

cover1 = measure_coverage_from_string(fun_def, (3, 1))
print("Original coverage:", cover1)
print("------------------------------")
cover2 = measure_coverage_from_string(fun_def_new, (3, 1))
print("New coverage:", cover2)
```

The output when running the code would be as follows, the 75% coverage at the first case is still 50% of code + 25% from function definition which is not executed second time:

```
3
Original coverage: 75.0
------------------------------
3
New coverage: 50.0
```

This output is unexpected, because the second function "fun_def_new" should print out parameter b and import the function from scratch which means coverage should take account function definition.

The expected output would be:

```
3
Original coverage: 75.0
------------------------------
3
1
New coverage: 100.0
```

I hope there is another option besides using timer of 1 sec or:

```
code = exec(compile(code_string, "<string>", "exec"))
locals()["fun"](a, b)
```

In both of these cases it is not possible to use python coverage to measure code coverage on the functions with given attributes.

Comment: Why are you calling reload() at all?  In the previous line you called load_module(), so how can the module have changed at that point?  Also, have you tried calling importlib.invalidate_caches() before the load_module() statement?

Comment: I was hoping for this reload to re-do the whole importing process and load my module from scratch, which is unfortunately not the case. I already did try to use importlib.invalidate_caches(), but id did not work, but thank you for the suggestion!